# Fatal error after changes to functions.php, even with original file

Tags: functions, debug, fatal-error

Getting `Fatal Error: Cannot redeclare theme_feature_setup()` message after code changing in the functions.php file. I've tried deleting functions.php file and uploading the previous version but I still get the same error message.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

included in config.php file.

Also NO error.log file is created in wp-content.

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Cannot redeclare bean_feature_setup() (previously declared in htdocs/wp-content/themes/koi-child/functions.php:33) in htdocs/wp-content/themes/koi/functions.php on line 33
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Have you upgraded any of your server side files? Apache, PHP etc. during your upgrades / changes?

Comment: No, just the changes done for functions.php file and that's it.

Comment: what theme is that? what is the full error message? this should have the locations of the (two ?) files where the function gets defined.

Comment: Have a look at the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, removed my first answer, that is why it is important to give as much info in your question as possible. You cannot copy functions from your parent theme to your child theme. You also cannot coipy the parent themes functions.php to your child theme

The only time you can keep the same function name between parent and child theme  is when the parent theme is enclosed in a `if (function exist()` hook.

Comment: Okay, problem solved. Thanks for the help. Q: But why isn't error.log file been created in wp-content, when `WP_DEBUG_LOG` is set to `true`?